# unhashable type: 'list' while in function, but works well outside the function

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am going to write a function instead of my old line by line code but looks like it doesn't work.

This piece of  code works well:

```
    def gdp_fdi(odf, colname):
        tempo = odf[odf['id'].str.contains(temp, na=False)] 
        df = tempo[['id',colname]]
        return df

    def sortdf(df):
        df['id'] = pd.Categorical(df.id, categories = top20code, ordered = True)
        df.sort_values(by='id')
        return df
<THIS PART>
    top20 =fdi.sort_values('fdi_1987',ascending = False).groupby('fdi_1987').head(2)
    top20 = top20[['fdi_1987','id']].head(21)

    top20code = top20['id']
    top20code = top20code.to_string(index=False)
    top20code = top20code.split()

    temp = '|'.join(top20code)


    top20_name=gdp_fdi(wb,'name')
    top20_region=gdp_fdi(wb,'region')
    top20_gdp=gdp_fdi(gdp,'gdp_1987')

    sort20gdp=sortdf(top20_gdp)
    sort20region=sortdf(top20_region)
    sort20name=sortdf(top20_name)

    from functools import reduce

    lists=[sort20gdp,sort20region,sort20name]
    df = reduce(lambda df1, df2: pd.merge(left=df1, right=df2, on=["id"], how="inner"), lists)
    df['id'] = pd.Categorical(df.id, categories = top20code, ordered = True)
    df.sort_values(by='id')
    raw=df.sort_values(by='id')
    raw
</THIS PART>
```

but when I write it as a function, I use `'fdi_'+str(year)` instead of `'fdi_1987'` and write `<THIS PART>` as a function named `top20(year)`.

But when I run the fuction by `top20(1987)`, it sais I have

> unhashable type: 'list'

May I ask why? any tips for redesign the function?

Comment: There are about 200 hits for `https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=python+unhashable+type+list` ... at least 5 or so in the first 10 solve your question... I did not bother to check the remaining 190

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `list` cannot be used as a `key` in a `dictionary` because it is unhashable. You can use a `tuple` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Mutable objects are unhashable because their hash-value would change as they are modified, so the lookups would fail. Switch to an immutable type such as a string using `json.dumps(somelist)` or a tuple like `tuple(somelist)`